# Java error when compiling a simple program: class, interface, or enum expected

Tags: java, debugging, fibonacci

```
import java.util.*;

public static void main(String args[]){
    Fibo();
    
    Class Fibo(){
        int n1=0, sum;

        for(int i =0; i<10; i++){
            sum = i + n1;
            n1=n1+sum;
            System.out.println(""+sum);
        }
    }
}
```

All want to do is print the first 10 fibo numbers and then add functionality to tell the computer which fibo numbers I want to print. Say like the 1 millionth fibo number.

Comment: Your `main()` method should be under the `class` declaration. And there's no `Fibo()` method.

Comment: You have lot of errors in your code, I suggest you to start with basic Java tutorials first.

Comment: Ahh as always the internet Provides.

Answer (score 1):

So let's get to the problems of your provided code:

#### 1. Syntax of defining a Class

To define a class in Java, it should be something like this:

```java
class Fibo {

}
```

1. There should be no `()` at the end of `Fibo`.
2. You should use a lower case `c` instead of upper case `C`. That is a keyword in Java and it is case-sensitive.

And sometimes you would see there is a keyword `public` in front of `class`:

```java
public class Fibo {

}
```

With `public`, you can access the `class` outside the `Package`. And I leave it to you if you want to explore more.

#### 2. Always define your functions inside a Class

`public static void main(String[] args) {}` is a **function**. And you should always place your function *inside* a Class.

```java
public class Fibo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Your main running function
    }
}
```

#### 3. Proper way to call Function or Class

To call function or create a new Class object:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Below is a function call
        functionTwo();
        // Below is creating a new class, assuming you have another simple Class named ClassTwo with only default constructor
        ClassTwo classTwo = new ClassTwo();
    }
    
    private static void functionTwo() {
        System.out.println("Inside functionTwo");
    }
}
```

#### 4. Logic of getting your Fibonacci numbers

First of all, here are some Fibonacci numbers:
`0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233`

> The first number = 0
> The second number = 1
> The third number = The first number + The second number
> The fourth number = The second number + The third number
> ... and so on

So according to the above logic, we can write our function to generate Fibonacci numbers:

```java
public class Fibo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int target = 10;
        int firstNumber = 0;
        int secondNumber = 1;
        int nextNumber = 0;
        System.out.println(firstNumber); // Print out the First Number
        System.out.println(secondNumber); // Print out the Second Number
        // Because there is a logic starting from the Third Number
        // Here we use a for loop to repeat until we get to our target 10
        for (int i = 2; i < target; i++) {
            // Next number is equal to (i-2) + (i-1), where i = current number
            nextNumber = firstNumber + secondNumber;
            // Print out the current number
            System.out.println(nextNumber);
            // As a for loop proceeds to the next one, we also need to update
            // our firstNumber and secondNumber with next one
            firstNumber = secondNumber;
            secondNumber = nextNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
```

Of course the above program can be simplified and also obtain the same result. But at this stage, having a clearer concept is of utmost importance.

#### 5. Remove unused Import

This is not fatal but as a good practice. Because in your code, you have not made use of any classes from other packages and therefore you do not need to import anything.

```
import java.util.*;
```

#### 6. Keep indentation

This is also not fatal but as a good practice. Which of the following code would like to see?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("This is a line");
     int a = 0;
 int b = 10;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      System.out.println("Line" + i);
      }
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("This is a line");
    int a = 0;
    int b = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Line" + i);
    }
}
```

And to your extra question. This time you have to make use of class that is beyond your package. So you need to make use of `import`. And that class is `Scanner`.

So the new full code should be like this:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fibo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter target: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int target = scanner.nextInt();
        int firstNumber = 0;
        int secondNumber = 1;
        int nextNumber = 0;
        System.out.println(firstNumber); // Print out the First Number
        System.out.println(secondNumber); // Print out the Second Number
        // Because there is a logic starting from the Third Number
        // Here we use a for loop to repeat until we get to our target 10
        for (int i = 2; i < target; i++) {
            nextNumber = firstNumber + secondNumber;
            System.out.println(nextNumber);
            firstNumber = secondNumber;
            secondNumber = nextNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Enter target: 10
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
```